# Выборка уникальных значений с условием

Tags: sql

[image: 123]

[image: 321]

Нужно выбрать уникальные значения `name` но что бы они были упорядочены по убыванию `viewersCount`

Comment: *что бы они были упорядочены по убыванию "viewersCount"* Какому именно? максимальному из значений для данного name? сумме всех значений? что-то ещё?

Comment: @Akina Да, максимальному к name

Comment: Ну тогда не DISTINCT, a честный GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,  max(viewersCount) AS viewersCount
FROM   games_stat
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY viewersCount DESC
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]